# onAttachedToWindow() is not being called

Tags: android

I am creating a object for a class FlyOutContainer like this

```
this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sample, null);
```

and in the class FlyOutContainer, i have the method `onAttachedToWindow()`

```
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Log.i("onAttachedToWindow", " occured");
        this.menu = this.getChildAt(0);

        this.content = this.getChildAt(1);

        this.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

hoping that this method should be called when i am creating the object for `this.root` but the method onAttachedWindow() is never get called. Why??

**UPDATE1**

```
<com.bibliotheque.android.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444488"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/home_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/search_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/mybooks_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/contact_btn_label" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:text="@string/about_btn_label" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/bookList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />           

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am using the FlyOutContainer to achieve the Slide in menu

Answer (score -1):

Have you actually added the view to the layout?

You need to call `addView(root)` on the parent you want to contain your FlyOutContainer, or use the 3 parameter method on the `LayoutInflater`:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sample, container, true)
```

where `container` is, again, the `ViewGroup` that will contain your new view.

Comment: can you tell me what should i use as ViewGroup?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to accomplish. In your layout you should have some ViewGroup (FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout,... ) to which you want to add the new FlyOutContainer.  Your `this.content`, maybe? If you update the question with your layout and explain what is FlyOutContainer supposed to do I could give you more detailed explanation.